# Angular2 reference enum in array in interface

Tags: angular, enums

I am to modify the following code which consists of an interface `Cat` that contains multiple `string`s, `Array`s, and `number`s, all of which are of various types. Here is my definition of Cat` in the ts file

```
export interface Cat {
  photos: string[];
  cost: number;
  breed: Breed;
  description: string;
  location: Location[];
  adoptionAgency: Agency;
  kittens: Kitten[];
}
```

What I am concerned with is the `breed` element (which stores an enum) in the `Kitten` array, which is defined as such

```
export interface Kitten {
  breed: KittenBreed;
  age: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

and here is the definition of the `KittenBreed`, which is an enum:

```
export enum KittenBreed {
  Persian,
  Siamese,
  Calico,
  Ragdoll,
  Shorthair
}
```

I want to be able to output info on a cat ONLY if the `KittenBreed` is `Persian`, `Siamese`, or `Shorthair`. I know I should use `ngIf`, but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly, nor am I sure if I'm even referencing the `KittenBreed` enum correctly.

```
<div *ngIf="{{cat.kitten.breed.KittenBreed}} == "Persian" || {{cat.kitten.breed.KittenBreed}} == "Siamese" || ""cat.kitten.breed.KittenBreed}} == "Shorthair" ">
  <p>success!</p>
</div>
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Kitten` is an Array, I'm assuming that somewhere you're using `*ngFor` on `kittens` and assigning it as `cat`

You don't need to use `cat.kitten.breed.KittenBreed` there. Instead, use `cat.kitten.breed` which has the actual value of the `KittenBreed`.

You also don't need to interpolate the properties using `{{ }}`

I'm adding `()` for readability's sake.

Also, in your interface, assign values to them or they'll get initialized to numbers.

```
export enum KittenBreed {
  Persian = 'Persian',
  Siamese = 'Siamese',
  Calico = 'Calico',
  Ragdoll = 'Ragdoll',
  Shorthair = 'Shorthair'
}
```

Then in your Component Class, do:

create a property named `KittenBreed` and assign it the value of `KittenBreed` which is your interface.

```
KittenBreed = KittenBreed;
```

The correct syntax should then be

```
<div *ngIf="(cat.kitten.breed === KittenBreed.Persian) || (cat.kitten.breed === KittenBreed.Siamese) || (cat.kitten.breed === KittenBreed.Shorthair)">
  <p> success! </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer to use the `enum` in the template. As long as you add it as a local property in the class. e.g. `...*ngIf="(cat.kitten.breed === KittenBreed.Persian) ...`;

Comment: you just need to assign it as a local  var in your component.ts file; e.g. `@Component(...) export class ClassName { KittenBreed = KittenBreed; ...}`

Comment: @joshvito, thanks for your inputs. I've updated my answer. :)

Comment: If you do the compare with the enum like I suggested, you don't need to assign string values to the enum members.

Comment: @joshvito - It would have been simpler to post your own answer. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Probably. :)

Comment: @joshvito, what if the Kitten's Breed is being stored and retrieved on an API as a String value instead of a number/index. I considered that while giving this answer.

Comment: @SiddAjmera - When using an enum, the values are expected to be saved as integers, aren't they?

Comment: From what I understand, `enum`s are just used as a tool to restrict assignment of a field to certian values. Doesn't necessarily mean it should be stored as an integer. Why do you think they give an option to initialize members of an `enum`?

Again, this is just what I think. I might be wrong. Please do enlighten me in that case.

Comment: Since the OP did not initialize his enum members, I assume that he uses them as integers.

Comment: I don't think OP shared their Component Class implementation. I guess we're both playing the guessing game here.

Comment: You should declare the enum differently and use Object.keys and indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the enum to validate the incoming value declaring it like above.

```
enum KittenBreed {
  Persian = 'Persian',
  Siamese = 'Siamese',
  Calico = 'Calico',
  Ragdoll = 'Ragdoll',
  Shorthair = 'Shorthair'
}
```

Then you just to use `object.key` and `indexof`.

```
public existKittenBreed(item: string): boolean {
    return Object.keys(KittenBreed).indexOf(<any>item) > -1;
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/valid-enum-in-array-in-interface)

Comment: This what I was talking about, great example bro.